# void * pointing to void * in a list

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I have a list like so:

```
void * head = [void * a] --> [void * b] --> [void * b] --> NULL
```

Given `void * head`, how can I iterate through the list?

Each `void *` points to another `void *`, with the final item in the list pointing to `NULL`.

I think I need to use `void **`, but I'm not completely sure. Each item in the list is not in contiguous memory.

Comment: You need some other type of pointer, not a `void*`, to extract what `head` points to.

Comment: struct node { void *value; struct node *next; }; struct node *head;...

Answer (score 1):

> I have a list like this [...]

This is not exactly a list - it is a multi-level pointer with the level unknown at compile time.

> I think I need to use `void **`, but I'm not completely sure

Yes, you are right! You can dereference the pointer one level at a time.

Here is what you can do:

- Set up a `while` loop that ends when `head` is `NULL`
- Inside the loop, make a `void **next`, and assign `head` to it
- Now *dereference* next, and assign the result to `head`, like this: `head = *next`
- Continue with the loop until `head` is `NULL`.

Each iteration of the loop removes another level of indirection, until the final pointer is reached.

Answer (score 0):

```
void *node = head;
while(node) {
    // do stuff with the node
    node = *((void**)node);
}
```